# notifySetDataChanged not working

Tags: android, listview, refresh, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `ListView` ,with custom adapter extending `BaseAdapter`. The list contains some messages, each of which is highlighted when unseen, but after clicking on it I changed the status into seen in `SQLite` DB and then used `notifySetDataChanged`, but it is still not refreshing.

This is my list:

```
public class Exams extends Fragment {
    List<NotificationMessages> messagesList = new ArrayList();
    private ListView lv;
    String[] subject;
    String[] message;
    String[] date;
    String[] seen;
    ListViewAdapter lva;
    Bundle bundle;

    public Exams() {
        // Required empty public constructor
   }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exams, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.examList);
    bundle = getArguments();
    final Dialog showdialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    try {
        dh.Open();
        messagesList = dh.getExams(bundle.getInt("studentId", 0));
        subject = new String[messagesList.size()];
        message = new String[messagesList.size()];
        date = new String[messagesList.size()];
        seen = new String[messagesList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < messagesList.size(); i++) {
            subject[i] = messagesList.get(i).getSubject().toString();
            message[i] = messagesList.get(i).getMessage().toString();
            date[i] = messagesList.get(i).getDate_scheduled().toString();
            seen[i] = messagesList.get(i).getStatus().toString();
        }
        lva = new ListViewAdapter(getContext(), subject, message, date, seen);
        lv.setAdapter(lva);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                showdialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                showdialog.setTitle(messagesList.get(position).getSubject());
                //TextView sub = (TextView)showdialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogsubject);
                TextView msg = (TextView) showdialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogmessage);
                TextView dat = (TextView) showdialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogdate);
                TextView tim = (TextView) showdialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogtime);
                //sub.setText(messagesList.get(position).getSubject());
                msg.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
                tim.setText("Time : " + messagesList.get(position).getDate_scheduled().substring(11));
                dat.setText("Date : " + messagesList.get(position).getDate_scheduled().substring(0, 10));
                showdialog.setCancelable(true);
                showdialog.show();
                DatabaseHandler dsh = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
                try {
                    dsh.Open();
                    int seenMsg = dsh.seenMessage(Integer.parseInt(messagesList.get(position).getMessage_recipientID()), bundle.getInt("studentId", 0));
                    Log.d("MessagesExamsSeen", "" + seenMsg);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.d("Message not seen", "");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dsh.close();
                lva.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Error", " " + e1);
    }
    dh.close();
    return view;
}
```

And this is my Adapter class :

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private String[] subject;
private String[] message;
private String[] date_scheduled;
private String[] seen;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] subject, String[] message, String[] date, String[] seen){
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
    this.date_scheduled = date;
    this.seen = seen;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return message.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view =convertView;
    if(convertView==null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, null);
    }
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rl);
    TextView sub = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subject);
    TextView msg = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message);
    TextView date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    if(seen[position].equals("seen")){
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    else if(seen[position].equals("unseen")){
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDADADA"));
    }
    // Setting all values in listview
    sub.setText(subject[position]);
    if(message[position].length()>=30){
        msg.setText(message[position].substring(0,30)+"..................");
    }
    else{
        msg.setText(message[position]);
    }
    date.setText(date_scheduled[position].substring(0,10));


    return view;
}
```

}

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating your DB but you are not fetching the updated values again from the DB. You need to fetch the updated values from you DB and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

This would solve the issue you are facing.

**Solution 1**

It should be something like this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exams, container, false);
lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.examList);
bundle = getArguments();
final Dialog showdialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
try {
    getDataFromDB();
    lv.setAdapter(lva);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            showdialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            showdialog.setTitle(messagesList.get(position).getSubject());
            //TextView sub = (TextView)showdialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogsubject);
            TextView msg = (TextView) showdialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogmessage);
            TextView dat = (TextView) showdialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogdate);
            TextView tim = (TextView) showdialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogtime);
            //sub.setText(messagesList.get(position).getSubject());
            msg.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
            tim.setText("Time : " + messagesList.get(position).getDate_scheduled().substring(11));
            dat.setText("Date : " + messagesList.get(position).getDate_scheduled().substring(0, 10));
            showdialog.setCancelable(true);
            showdialog.show();
            DatabaseHandler dsh = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
            try {
                dsh.Open();
                int seenMsg = dsh.seenMessage(Integer.parseInt(messagesList.get(position).getMessage_recipientID()), bundle.getInt("studentId", 0));
                Log.d("MessagesExamsSeen", "" + seenMsg);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.d("Message not seen", "");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dsh.close();
            getDataFromDB
            lva.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("Error", " " + e1);
}
dh.close();
return view;
}

public void getDataFromDB()
{
    dh.Open();
    messagesList = dh.getExams(bundle.getInt("studentId", 0));
    subject = new String[messagesList.size()];
    message = new String[messagesList.size()];
    date = new String[messagesList.size()];
    seen = new String[messagesList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < messagesList.size(); i++) 
        {
            subject[i] = messagesList.get(i).getSubject().toString();
            message[i] = messagesList.get(i).getMessage().toString();
            date[i] = messagesList.get(i).getDate_scheduled().toString();
            seen[i] = messagesList.get(i).getStatus().toString();
        }

    lva = new ListViewAdapter(getContext(), subject, message, date, seen);
}
```

**Solution 2**

Add

```
 seen[position] = "1"; // or whatever your new state should be.
```

before

```
 lva.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i was thinkin that was the problem too, but i have no idea how to update DB without reopening the fragment...

Comment: That is what I have explained in my **Solution 1**

Comment: The idea is: After changing the status "seen", you need to reload your adapter with updated data and then call `notifiyDataSetChanged`. I can't run and test your code. I just gave an idea how to do it. You ll have to debug a little.

Comment: lol ya i know, m just trying , well thanx though i got the idea!!

Answer (score 2):

Use Finally block and insert the following code:

lva.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this

put your 
public void onresume()
{
adapter.notifySetDataChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you check your Database updated or not properly.
 After that call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method in `getView()` of `ListViewAdapter` before `return view;`.

Answer (score 0):

You must look at the constructor of your adapter, it copies the arrays in new instances and work with these new arrays, the new arrays which the adapter is using are not updating, so it's totally normal that nothing will be changing when ye call `notifySetDataChanged`.